# Zybo development board for RISC-V

Tags: riscv

I am going to port UEFI on RISC-V platform and plan to buy few Zybo boards for the development. Just want to make sure if RISC-V simulator works well on Zybo board?
Any advice?

Thanks

Abner

Answer (score 1):

Zybo support was last confirmed back in July. It is possible the move to Vivado 2015.2 may have caused some issues, but it shouldn't be too bad to fix.

Both the Zedboard and zc706 are confirmed to work currently. In general, it seems Vivado seems to support those two board better than the Zybo.

Comment: Thanks! I see.
I think I will try Zybo first. It is much cheaper than others. :)
Abner